# Finding the address of the proxied to address of a proxy

Tags: etherscan, proxy-contracts

This smart contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53#code) is a proxy. You can tell this by clicking on 'Read as Proxy'.

However, when one looks at the 'Read Contract' tab and one clicks on the `implementation` data item, it reports the implementation address as `0x`.

I notice in the code that the `implementation` function is not public, so I suppose that's why it's not returning a value, but then...

**Question:** How does Etherscan know that the contract is a proxy and what fourbyte code does it use to query the proxied-to address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementation is stored as value in `IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT` (see the [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53#code)), so you can get the underlined Contract with:

```js
let proxyContract = "0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53";
let storagePosition = "0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3";
let result = await web3Client.eth.getStorageAt(proxyContract, storagePosition);

// > 0x0000000000000000000000005864c777697bf9881220328bf2f16908c9afcd7e
```

`implementation` method you are calling is allowed only with admin rights. I think, this method is there for testing or a quick check only.

Etherscan also shows `0x5864c777697bf9881220328bf2f16908c9afcd7e` as a target implementation contract.

**But**, what I'm wondering is, why when reading `totalSupply` in proxy [`0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53#readProxyContract) it returns `9023954154960000000000000000`, but directly inside the implementation [`0x5864c777697bf9881220328bf2f16908c9afcd7e`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5864c777697bf9881220328bf2f16908c9afcd7e#readContract) it returns `0`. May be smbd. here will have a clue.

**EDIT**

Ok, found it - storage belongs to the proxy, means the proxy is like a storage container, and when it calls implementation methods, they are called in the proxy storage context.

[0x5864c777697bf9881220328bf2f16908c9afcd7e#code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5864c777697bf9881220328bf2f16908c9afcd7e#code)

```js
/**
 * @title BUSDImplementation
 * NOTE: The storage defined here will actually be held in the Proxy
 * contract and all calls to this contract should be made through
 * the proxy, including admin actions done as owner or supplyController.
 * Any call to transfer against this contract should fail
 * with insufficient funds since no tokens will be issued there.
 */
```

**EDIT**

Implementation Storage Slot

Usually, the unstructed pattern is used to persist the Implementation Contract Address, as otherwise it could conflict with the implementation.
There is also a standard for this https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967 , but before `openzeppelin` had its own approach https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/

In both cases the slots are **hardcoded**:

- `bytes32(uint256(keccak256('eip1967.proxy.implementation')) - 1))` resolves to `0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc`
- `keccak256("org.zeppelinos.proxy.implementation")` resolves to `0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3`

*I don't know, if from ABI you can distinguish both this standard implementations, please check the differences, but anyway you can try to read both storage slots.*

If the contract uses not standard proxy patterns, then you have to know the implementation.

Comment: I understand your solution thank you. If I’m not mistaken, the solution needs me to have the source code so that I can find the storage location. Is that right? I was looking for a solution that was generic that didn’t require the source code. With the ABI I know there’s an implementation function without the source code i don’t know anything about the storage locations.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush see my last edits, do you have any other questions?

Comment: For an example  (in C++) of finding the proxy, see here: https://github.com/TrueBlocks/trueblocks-core/blob/develop/src/libs/etherlib/ethcall.cpp#L513

Of course, there are many other examples in other languages. Find them by searching for the hex codes in the example.